# Chrome scrolling is choppy on external display

Tags: google-chrome, macbook, external-display, scrolling

When I go to this page https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery **the scrolling is choppy**. The same eg. for gitlab when scrolling longer diffs https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/15670/diffs

The weird thing is however, that it's choppy **only when the window is being scrolled on external monitor**. When I scroll the same pages on built-in screen, it's smooth.

What can be the cause of this issue?

*I'm on macOS 10.13.3 and latest Chrome version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

Comment: Sounds like you might be using a wireless or USB based video adapter on the external monitor.

Comment: We have encoutered the problem on mac air 2015 (displayport), mac pro 2015 (displayport) and mac pro 2017 (usb->hdmi).  The USB would eventually make sense but those displayports should be good enough I guess.

Comment: Ok. Yes, USB to HDMI would probably have this problem. You should update your question to clearly indicate you are using Apple products.

Comment: It's in the last sentence -> `macOs`. Adding tag